# How to show thumbnails fit in view

Tags: ipad

I have a problem to show tumbnails fit in view. I know it can be done in Interface Buidlder by choosing mode with "Aspect fit". However, is there a way to archive this by code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yeh it is possible

```
        [UIImage View setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
```